# Background image not showing on gh pages

Tags: html, css, github

Hello i searched for answers but i didnt find any that arent case sensitive related. Locally all works great but when i upload to gh pages it doesnt add background image. I checked case sensitive and everything to tie it all, first  isaw maybe image is too big or something but now i see thats not the problem if someone can check and tell me what may be causing the problem thx in advance. My repo of project https://github.com/SupremeSalvatore/01DrumKit and my gh page https://supremesalvatore.github.io/01DrumKit/

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: The file `https://supremesalvatore.github.io/01DrumKit/css/style.css` does not exist.

Comment: ok thx for points how should i ask qustion with 2nd comment i disagree everything is in that repository since you can probably see letters are styled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 9 of your css reads `background: url("/images/drums.jpeg") bottom center;`. This means the file is being searched for in the same folder as where style.css is held:

`https://supremesalvatore.github.io/01DrumKit/css/drums.jpg` which isn't where it is.

To have the code search for the image in the root folder add `..` before the /images folder so it reads as below and this should fix it.

`background: url("../images/drums.jpeg") bottom center;`

Comment: Oh thx it worked like charm this was amateur mistake by me since my editor did connect those 2 even tho it was bad...